# How to extract a set of strings between to characters or words using sed

Tags: unix, sed

I have a particular sentence like this -

```
|/billing/gcdr/ftpdir|fw43/collectors/ANHMCA04ANT|
```

I would required to extract the following portion from this particular sentence -

```
/billing/gcdr/ftpdir
```

Is there any possiblity that i can do it with sed ? If yes , please help me.

Answer (score 3):

along with `sed` and `awk` you can also use `cut`. using `cut`:

`echo "|/billing/gcdr/ftpdir|fw43/collectors/ANHMCA04ANT|" | cut -d'|' -f2`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a `sed` solution, but if you can live with [awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html):

```
echo "|/billing/gcdr/ftpdir|fw43/collectors/ANHMCA04ANT|"| awk -F"|" '{print $2}'
```

will yield:

```
/billing/gcdr/ftpdir
```

*Explanation of awk command:*

```
awk -F"|" '{print $2}'
```

`-F="|"` specifies the "field separator" - it separates/groups the input line into different fields using the `'|'` character (rather than using whitepace by default) and then prints the second field of that line.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can easily do that:

```
sed 's/^|//;s/|.*//;'
```

The first `sed` command (`s/^|//`) will remove first `|` symbol, and the second one (`s/|.*//`) will remove next `|` and all symbols after that.

To test it run in console:

```
echo "|/billing/gcdr/ftpdir|fw43/collectors/ANHMCA04ANT|" | sed 's/^|//;s/|.*//;'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo '|/billing/gcdr/ftpdir|fw43/collectors/ANHMCA04ANT|' | 
sed 's/^|\([^|]*\).*/\1/'
/billing/gcdr/ftpdir
```